# mac ports python32 tkinter module not loading

Tags: python

not able to launch my python script.  It is complaining that Tkinter module is nowhere to be found....

Uhm, what am I missing?

```
from Tkinter import *
ImportError: No module named Tkinter


$ sudo port installed | grep py
 py32-tkinter @3.2.2_0 (active)
 python32 @3.2.2_0 (active)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are running the macports version of python and not the OSX version.

```
which python
```

Should return

```
/opt/local/bin/python
```

If its returning `/usr/bin/python` instead then your path needs to be adjusted.

```
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
```

You can run the above line from  your command prompt to test if it works. If it does work  you will need to put it in your ~/.profile for it to persist across sessions.